# Losing parts in Link List in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to make a link list and I'm having trouble with the concept with linking the middle part, I'm just doing a little pseudo-code right now, haven't actually coded anything.

```
(struct pointers) *current, *ahead, *behind, *begin;

(behind)-->(current)-->(ahead) //This is what I want to do

behind->next = current;
current->next = ahead;
```

Is this the proper way to break and connect the list? Without losing anything..

Comment: I would recommend the write-test-debug method of programming.

Comment: @Horus: I'd recommend the "understand what you're doing"-write-test-debug method of programming. Without understanding you'll never write a tight enough test suite to catch the edge cases or even most of the "normal" cases.

Comment: But for something like this, it should be a very short piece of code.  Code with this level of complexity should be hackable very quickly, and the experience garnered is huge, when at the level of programming shown.  Algo is better learned by doing than asking.

Comment: yea prob have to figure what I'm doing first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have looks correct but rather incomplete. One of the unwritten rules of programming is that you cannot write a linked list implementation correctly the first time. There are four cases you need to deal with:

1. Insert into an empty list
2. Insert into a non-empty list
3. Removing the first element from the list
4. Removing any other element from the list

There are also doubly-linked lists, where each element has a pointer to both the previous element and the next element. That makes it easier to handle things like removal of a random element without traversing the list, but can be trickier to get right.

Comment: 5. Remove from a single-item list.